# How do I use sklearn.metrics.pairwise pairwise_distances with callable metric?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, hdbscan

I'm doing some behavior analysis where I track behaviors over time and then create n-grams of those behaviors.

```
sample_n_gram_list = [['scratch', 'scratch', 'scratch', 'scratch', 'scratch'],
                      ['scratch', 'scratch', 'scratch', 'scratch', 'smell/sniff'],
                      ['scratch', 'scratch', 'scratch', 'sit', 'stand']]
```

I want to be able to cluster these n-grams, but I need to create a pre-computed distance matrix using a custom metric. My metric appears to work fine, but when I try to create the distance matrix using the sklearn function, I get an error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'scratch'
```

I've looked at the documentation https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances.html and it's not particularly clear on this topic.

Anyone familiar with how to use this properly?

---

The full code is below:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import math
import hashlib 
import networkx as nx
import itertools
import hdbscan
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import pairwise_distances

def get_levenshtein_distance(path1, path2):
    """
    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance
    :param path1:
    :param path2:
    :return:
    """
    matrix = [[0 for x in range(len(path2) + 1)] for x in range(len(path1) + 1)]

    for x in range(len(path1) + 1):
        matrix[x][0] = x
    for y in range(len(path2) + 1):
        matrix[0][y] = y

    for x in range(1, len(path1) + 1):
        for y in range(1, len(path2) + 1):
            if path1[x - 1] == path2[y - 1]:
                matrix[x][y] = min(
                    matrix[x - 1][y] + 1,
                    matrix[x - 1][y - 1],
                    matrix[x][y - 1] + 1
                )
            else:
                matrix[x][y] = min(
                    matrix[x - 1][y] + 1,
                    matrix[x - 1][y - 1] + 1,
                    matrix[x][y - 1] + 1
                )

    return matrix[len(path1)][len(path2)]

sample_n_gram_list = [['scratch', 'scratch', 'scratch', 'scratch', 'scratch'],
                      ['scratch', 'scratch', 'scratch', 'scratch', 'smell/sniff'],
                      ['scratch', 'scratch', 'scratch', 'sit', 'stand']]

print("should be 0")
print(get_levenshtein_distance(sample_n_gram_list[1],sample_n_gram_list[1]))
print("should be 1")
print(get_levenshtein_distance(sample_n_gram_list[1],sample_n_gram_list[0]))
print("should be 2")
print(get_levenshtein_distance(sample_n_gram_list[0],sample_n_gram_list[2]))

clust_number = 2
distance_matrix = pairwise_distances(sample_n_gram_list, metric=get_levenshtein_distance)
clusterer = hdbscan.HDBSCAN(metric='precomputed')
clusterer.fit(distance_matrix)
clusterer.labels_
```

Comment: getting same error. Is there any solution available?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because the `pairwise_distances` in sklearn is designed to work for numerical arrays (so that all the different inbuilt distance functions can work properly), but you are passing a string list to it. If you can convert the strings to numbers (encode a string to specific number) and then pass it, it will work properly.

A fast numpy way of doing that is:

```
# Get all the unique strings in the input data
uniques = np.unique(sample_n_gram_list)
# Output:
# array(['scratch', 'sit', 'smell/sniff', 'stand'])

# Encode the strings to numbers according to the indices in "uniques" array
X = np.searchsorted(uniques, sample_n_gram_list)

# Output:
# array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],    <= scratch is assigned 0, sit = 1 and so on
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 2],
         [0, 0, 0, 1, 3]])


# Now this works
distance_matrix = pairwise_distances(X, metric=get_levenshtein_distance)

# Output
# array([[0., 1., 2.],
         [1., 0., 2.],
         [2., 2., 0.]])
```

Comment: I had considered this, but dismissed it because I thought 'surely, it's not required' :)